# Is it appropriate to use ish-suffix with languages? (ex. Englishish)

Tags: suffixes

Is it appropriate to use ish-suffix for “it's sort of English but not quite”?

> Standard Russian order is “surname, first, patronymic”, because there is special abbreviation "ФИО". “first, patronymic, surname” is Englishish order.

Comment: What is your goal here? What do you understand the -ish suffix to do?

Comment: No -- *English* is both the name of the language and the adjectival form. ... Likewise, *Russian* is both the name and the adjective. (Actually, both started as adjectives!)

Comment: It's weird with English because you're doubling the -ish... but the reason I asked the question in my first comment is that, in very informal English, it's not uncommon to add a second suffix, occasionally -ish, to change the meaning, so someone might say "German-ish" to mean "it's sort of German but not quite". That being said, if it is *actually German*, Stoney is correct... it's already an adjective.

Comment: “first, patronymic, surname” is not English order, because English doesn't have patronymic, but it is kind of English, because there is “first, second, surname”. So “kind of English” = Englishish, isn't it?

Comment: As you'll note in my example, the use of the hyphen actually helps clarify that it's being done for effect... "English-ish" is how I'd do it if that's your intention.

Comment: Related question on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/when-is-it-appropriate-if-at-all-to-use-the-suffix-ish

Comment: Other options are -y and -esque. http://www.glossophilia.org/?p=7521

Comment: Yes, hyphen! Thank you, it is answer. Usually there is simple words: “girlish”,“greenish”, so I didn't think about hyphen.

Comment: I have heard the term "Engl-ish" as a very informal (tongue-in-cheek) way to describe a phrase or sentence that resembles English, but isn't quite parsable as English. Here, it refers to a poor use of language, not merely a stylistic convention as you seem to be describing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you recognize that it's pretty informal English, sure. You can add -ish, -y or -esque to some words to give it the sense of "almost but not quite". There are some minor differences between the three, so you might want to [take some time to read up](http://www.glossophilia.org/?p=7521) on them a bit but I think -ish in your example works pretty well. It might be a bit of a mouthful to say, though.

> In English, they usually say first name then family/surname, so saying first, patronymic, surname would be "English-ish" (and Russian-esque).

While in most uses of this you don't need the hyphen (greenish, girlish as you mentioned in a comment) but in some cases it really helps to have it as it sets the suffix apart and makes it more evident, which makes sense since when you do say it, you're probably going to accent it more strongly.